# react) 'npm run build' is not working. and I got this message " Error: Cannot find module 'jsonfile/utils'"

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HogGz.jpg)

..

Comment: Have you ran npm install? Have you tried removing node_modules and re-running npm install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `npm install` again. If you already have a package-lock.json, you can also try `npm ci` to run a clean install of your dependencies.

Comment: Glad it worked! can you mark my answer as the correct answer? (trying to build my rep here) Thanks!